# Beaker caching performance guideline

Tags: python, cherrypy, beaker

I was implemented [beaker](http://beaker.groovie.org/caching.html) with a cherrypy application, but after some requests, the beaker response time increases about 10-14 seconds.

i think after including 500 to 1000 items in cache, beaker goes down.

all cached types are simple(str,int,list,tuple,...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Found the problem,
The beaker have some performance problems with *file* type back-end.
simply i changed the

```
'cache.type' : 'file'
```

to:

```
'cache.type' : 'dbm'
```

and everything is so good!!!

when type is *file* beaker uses python pure *pickle* library to serialize the object. and pickle does not good for large objects.